# Consider $Y=\mathbb{R} \times \{0,\infty\}$ and the equivalence relation $(x,0) \sim (\frac{1}{x}, \infty)$. Find the quotient space $Y / \sim$

Tags: general-topology

Let $Y=\mathbb{R} \times \{0, \infty\}$ and consider the equivalence relation generated by $(x,0) \sim (\frac{1}{x}, \infty)$ for $x \neq 0$. Identify the quotient space $Y / \sim$.

My attempt: I know the quotient space $Y / \sim$ is the set of all equivalence classes $\{[x,y]: x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \{0, \infty\}\}$. So $Y / \sim$ would be given by

$[(x,y)]=\{x,y\} \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in \{0, \infty\} $

$[(x,0)]=\{(x,0), (\frac{1}{x}, \infty)\} \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Given this is [tag:differential-geometry], I assume we are considering $Y / \sim$ as a topological space, not just a set with an equivalence relation?

Comment: Yes! But I don't really understand how the answer would be in this case

Comment: Differential geometry is not my area, but I'm pretty sure it's a circle. Think about the $\Bbb{R} \times \{\infty\}$ line as being partitioned into three parts: $(-\infty, 0) \times \{\infty\}$, $\{0\} \times \{\infty\}$, and $(0, \infty) \times \{\infty\}$. The first and third parts get identified with parts of $\Bbb{R} \times \{0\}$, leaving only one new point $(0, \infty)$ (which, to be clear, is not an interval). This point is "near" $(x, \infty)$ for small $x$, which makes it "near" $(x, 0)$ for large $x$. So, we are adding one extra point to form a circle.

Comment: As @TheoBendit explains it is useful to view the original space as two copies of the real line. The equivalence relation glues their points pairwise except for the origins.

Comment: Your attempt is not totally correct: $[(x,y)]=\{x,y\}$ for $x=0$ and $y\in\{0,infty\}$, not for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The differential geometry tag is not appropriate. I have changed it to general topology. This is about the quotient topology, pure and simple.

Answer (score 3):

$Y/\sim$ is a circle. If you want a intuitive proof, check the drawing, however, remark that if you call $\infty$ "1", this is clearly the real projective space $\mathbb R\mathbb P^1$: indeed, the two lines are the two affine charts $y=0$ and $y=1$, which cover $\mathbb R\mathbb P^1$.[image]